# Linq to SQL: Updating dataGridView after SubmitChanges isn't working

Tags: c#, sql, linq

First time I've worked with LINQ, and I've encountered a strange problem.   I'm using MS SQL 2008.  If I alter a row and SubmitChanges(), I can see the changes in the SQL Server Management Studio, but when I query to refill my dataGridViews with the updated information, I get the old version of the data.

Below is a change in my data:

```
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 1)
        {
            var query = from eq in db.equipments
                        where eq.SerNo == serial
                        select eq;

            foreach (equipment equip in query)
            {
                equip.Loc = textBox1.Text;
                equip.Owner = "Evisive";
                equip.Status = updatedStatus;
                equip.SystemName = "";
            }

            db.SubmitChanges();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a Destination");
        }
```

Again, that part works (changes the data in the database).  Below is where I try to update the table (the part that doesn't seem to work):

```
    public void Update_EquipmentGrid()
    {
        BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
        b.DataSource = from eq in db.equipments
                       select eq;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = b;
    }
```

Is this not the right way to update a table?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out.  This link explains it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386982(v=vs.110).aspx

Code should be:

```
        InventoryDataContext dba = new InventoryDataContext();

        BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
        b.DataSource = from eq in dba.equipments
                       select eq;

        dataGridView2.DataSource = b;
```

Not sure why, but you need to create a new instance of the DataContext each time it is updated.

Comment: You could call [Refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.refresh?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_Linq_DataContext_Refresh_System_Data_Linq_RefreshMode_System_Collections_IEnumerable_) or [a ClearCache extension](http://blog.robustsoftware.co.uk/2008/11/clearing-cache-of-linq-to-sql.html) on the DataContext

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
```

before

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = b;
```

Also try converting your data to list before assigning.

```
b.DataSource = (from eq in db.equipments
                select eq).ToList();
```

Comment: The first suggestion seems to have no effect, and the second one disables the search function on the dataGridView.

Comment: What is the return type of the db.equipments? Is it Enumerable<>? Also is the AutoGenerateColumns property set to true?

Comment: Not sure how to find that.  When I hover over it, it's listed as System.Data.Linq.Table<equipment> InventoryDataContext equipments.  And yes, the AutoGenerateColumns property is true.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps you

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q142798

example:

```
var orders = DBInterface.dcAPI.OrderInfos;
var b = orders.GetNewBindingList();
dgOrders.ItemsSource = b;
```